# SilverStripe remove CSV Export button

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to remove the **Export to CSV** button in the top of a `GridField` in `ModelAdmin`.

I can't seem to find the class that creates the button (`GridFieldExportButton` right?). I'm guessing there is a function that populates the GridField with buttons / "actions" which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove the scaffolded GridField for relationships...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    ...

    private static $has_many= array(
        'OtherDataObjects' => 'OtherDataObject'
    );

    ...

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if($grid = $fields->dataFieldByName('OtherDataObjects'))
            $grid->getConfig()
                ->removeComponentsByType('SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldExportButton');

        return $fields;
    }

    ...

}
```

If you are making the GridField then just add this when you create the field...

```
$gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldExportButton');
```

If you are looking for a gridfield that isn't within a data object edit form and is actually...

```
class MyAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    ...

    function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

        if($this->modelClass == 'MyDataObjectName') {
            $form->Fields()
                ->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))
                ->getConfig()
                ->removeComponentsByType('SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldExportButton');
        }
        return $form;
    }

    ...
}
```

Setting model_importers to empty will do the reverse and remove the import ...

```
class MyAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    ...

    static $model_importers = array();

    ...
}
```

Comment: That seems to get rid of the import function, not the export button. Also valuable by the way, since I want to hide that from user as well.

Comment: Indeed! Updated to include the removal of the button you actually asked about!

Comment: 'MyFieldName' should be the DataObject class name?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why any $db field should be addressed to remove the export button. The DataObject has several $db fields, which one should I put in there?

Comment: ah, I'm going to get there on this one..  the issue is that you have a gird field named after a relationship (like a has many or many many) it is that that should be there... this is the name of the "grid field"  if you have just created your own gridfield then just use $grid->getConfig()            ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldExportButton'); on that field to remove it.

Comment: The thing is, this dataobject has no relation set (ie has_many). It's pulled into a ModelAdmin extension (custom cms section) using $managed_models=array('DataObjectClassName');

Comment: Ok... added a case for that too... I _must_ have covered every angle now lol :)

Comment: Haha you sticked to it to the end. The last addition worked succesfully. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure if this solution was meant for ss3, but in order for this to work in ss4, you need to write the full path to the component, `removeComponentsByType('SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldExportButton')` – otherwise the component can't be found.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru absolutely, this is for SS3, SS4 stable release was end of 2017, over a year after this post

Comment: Ah, comparing post dates with release dates. That's a helpful trick.

Comment: Also I wrote the post and I never moved over to SS3 :)

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru you should add yours as an answer as I've confirmed that works it SS4

Comment: @Rudiger as I've just seen this I've updated, happy this post still helps some 4 years later :)